# IN my case Button1.setEnable(True); is not working

Tags: java, android

in my case when i try to set the button enable using BUTTON1.setEnable(false);

so the emulator does not start the apk...

i want to create a game level menu with some buttons Enable and rest of the buttons Disable .as each button is a game level .. so if my integer flag has value 5 so first five levels buttons should be active and rest of the buttons be disable.... but i could not even set a single button disable ... please help am i missing some concept with buttons ... where to change their state in OnResume() or in OnCreate();

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 b1.setEnabled(false);

}
}
```

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: hellow .. my problem is simple Buttun1.setEnable(false) is not working in my android project ... it works xml way .. but not by jav way

Comment: `BUTTON1.setEnable(false);` Is your Button actually called `BUTTON1` (all caps)?! Do you even know that Java is case sensitive?

Comment: Try my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)` into your `onCreate()` method.

**Try this:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: dude you are a pro its really working ... thanks finally i can continue with  my game .............thanks ...........

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an android development environment at hand right now, but I could imagine, that it has somethin to do, with the view (and therefore the button) not beining available at the time of the initiation of the attribute b1. Could you try the following:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getButton1().setEnabled(false);

    }

    private Button getButton1() {
        return (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

Comment: 04-20 13:08:34.380 1580-1695/? E/SQLiteLog: (1032) statement aborts at 18: [INSERT INTO shortcut_and_widget_previews(name,preview_bitmap,size) VALUES (?,?,?)] 
04-20 13:08:34.380 1580-1695/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Widget:UserHandle{0}/com.android.deskclock/com.android.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider preview_bitmap=[B@19f1405b size=260x197
                                                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)

Answer (score 0):

so in order to set buttons Enable/Disable one have to declare the buttons into OnCreate ...otherwise it wont find the view of the button and show errors ...

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

}

is the right way .............thanks everone

Comment: May I know why you are posting just a copy of my answer and marked as accepted? You have accepted my answer as right answer and now you posted same answer and accepted it. Why? whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: okey... but never do this again. As there is same accepted answer you don't need to answer it again with similar answer. If there is no helpful answer and you solved it by yourself only then you can give answer and accept it. There is no problem. I hope you understand. Read this >> https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  Thank you :)